# 'a trip for my wife and self'

Tags: reflexives

Can one use 'self' as substitute for 'myself' in 'a trip for my wife and self'? I have noticed that using 'myself' there raises other grammatical issues strictly related with the so_called "Toff's error", which I want to avoid!

Comment: What's wrong with using *me*?

Comment: @Andrew Leach My wife does not like it! She says that there is little emphasis.

Comment: I think you should edit the question and say why you don't like each of *I*, *me* and *myself* and what you hope to achieve by using *self*. (I don't understand what you mean by "little emphasis". Emphasis of what?)

Comment: As we have to say over and over again, it all depends on context, on the effect the speaker is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Why are you unconfortable with "little emphasis"? I have no doubts on its meaning!

Comment: He(@Andrew) is not uncomfortable with what you said, we want people to be a little more precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use 'self', but you shouldn't. If you ("I") are the subject of the clause you should employ 'myself'; otherwise you should employ 'me':

- I arranged a trip for my wife and myself.
- Herbert arranged a trip for my wife and me.

Other devices are available to secure emphasis. For instance, if you want to emphasize that your own participation in the trip is a happy bonus you might say "Herbert arranged a trip to Pago-Pago for both my wife and me." If your wife is still distressed you might say "Herbert arranged a trip for both my wife and for me", or even ".. for my wife - and me, myself as well!"

In any case, considerations beyond usage tend to discourage telling your wife to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

People will understand what you mean but it isn't correct usage. Myself is better although it sounds a bit formal and stilted. Tell you wife that you're going to say "me and my wife" and she's going to have to deal with it!